# Windows forgets Download folder location in Favorites

Tags: windows

I use a specific folder to download files. I changed the Download link in Favorites to point to that directory. I downloaded a file today by clicking on Download link and saved the file. Then I opened the specific folder and tried to find that file. It wasn't there. I downloaded again and Windows tried to overwrite. I checked it and Windows *defaulted it back* to User/Downloads folder.

Why did Windows do that without a given command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea as to why Windows does half the things it does - but when it's being difficult on an issue like this I've resorted to using mklink to replace the folder it wants to use with a link to the actual folder I want to use. then even if it uses the old default folder it will be writing into your preferred location.

I do this a lot for application settings that I want to preserve on a seperate drive letter to make backing up stuff I care about easier.

You'd remove/rename the existing Downloads folder under your user folder, and then launch cmd as admin and do something like:

cd \Users\yourusername

mklink /D Downloads D:\myfolder

Comment: Every browser I know of has a setting for its default download folder. It will use that location without regard to what may be on your Explorer Favorites list.